# How to add suffix to a column based on a value condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a df

```
 Sent   Words     Tags    POS
Sent1   Realt       O     NNP
Sent1   Need        O     NNP
Sent1   Guys        O     NNP
Sent2   20,000    Limit   PRP
Sent3    EUR     Currency NNP
```

Where ever the tag is 'O', it needs to be combined with its corresponding POS value. Ex- O-NNP
For other tags than O, leave the value as it is.

Desired output:

```
Sent    Words       Tags      POS
Sent1   Realt       O-NNP     NNP
Sent1   Need        O-NNP     NNP
Sent1   Guys        O-NNP     NNP
Sent2   20,000      Limit     PRP
Sent3    EUR        Currency   NNP
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) by compare for equal:

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].mask(df['Tags'].eq('O'), 'O_' + df['POS'])
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df.loc[df['Tags'].eq('O'), 'Tags'] = df['Tags'].str.cat(df['POS'], sep='_')
```

Working same like:

```
df.loc[df['Tags'].eq('O'), 'Tags'] = 'O_' + df['POS']
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['Tags'].eq('O'), 'Tags'] += '_' + df['POS']
```

---

```
print (df)
    Sent   Words      Tags  POS
0  Sent1   Realt     O_NNP  NNP
1  Sent1    Need     O_NNP  NNP
2  Sent1    Guys     O_NNP  NNP
3  Sent2  20,000     Limit  PRP
4  Sent3     EUR  Currency  NNP
```